# How to catch exceptions which is displaying in browsers console?

Tags: javascript, java

I want to test the list of HTTP URL connection status and it can be achievable using http URL connection and i'm getting response code 200 but link is not working. Because i'm seeing exceptions in the browser console.

Is there options to capture exception ?

Comment: did you try with a try/catch? try the request catch the exception? https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch

Comment: I'm not getting any error from response.then how would go to catch block to display the console.log .

Comment: You did not mention you were using promises. 
try with 
`request.get()
.then( (r) => {})
.catch(e => console.log(e))`